# How to read the file without encoding and extract desired urls with python3?

Tags: python-3.x, file, encoding, utf-8

Environment :python3.
There are many files ,some of them encoding with gbk,others encoding with utf-8. 
I want to extract all the jpg with regular expression

For s.html encoding with gbk.

```
tree = open("/tmp/s.html","r").read()
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 135: invalid start byte

```
tree = open("/tmp/s.html","r",encoding="gbk").read()
pat = "http://.+\.jpg"
result = re.findall(pat,tree)
print(result)
```

['http://somesite/2017/06/0_56.jpg']

It is a huge job to open all the files with specified encoding,i want a smart way to extract jpg urls in all the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they have mixed encoding, you could try one encoding and fall back to another:

```
# first open as binary
with open(..., 'rb') as f:
    f_contents = f.read()
    try:
        contents = f_contents.decode('UTF-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        contents = f_contents.decode('gbk')
    ...
```

If they are html files, you may also be able to find the encoding tag, or search them as binary with a binary regex:

```
contents = open(..., 'rb').read()
regex = re.compile(b'http://.+\.jpg')
result = regex.findall(contents)
# now you'll probably want to `.decode()` each of the urls, but you should be able to do that pretty trivially with even the `ASCII` codec
```

Though now that I think of it, you probably don't really want to use regex to capture the links as you'll then have to deal with html entities (`&amp;`) and may do better with something like [pyquery](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/)

Here's a quick example using pyquery

```
contents = open(..., 'rb').read()
pq = pyquery.PyQuery(contents)
images = pq.find('img')
for img in images:
   img = pyquery.PyQuery(img)
   if img.attr('src').endswith('.jpg')
       print(img.attr('src'))
```

Not on my computer with things installed, so mileage with these code samples may vary

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, and how I solved this is as follows.

In `get_file_encoding(filename)`, I first check if there is a BOM (Byte Order Mark) in the file, if so, get the encoding from the BOM. From the function: `get_file_bom_encoding(filename)`

If that did not return a value, I would get a list from the function: `get_all_file_encodings(filename)`

This list will have all encodings which the file can be opened in. For the purpose I was doing this, I just needed one, and I did not care about the rest, so I simply choose the first value of the list `file_encoding = str(encoding_list[0][0])`

This obviously is not accurate a 100% but at least it will give you either the correct encoding from the BOM, or it will give you a list of encodings in which the file can be opened. Or if you do this the same, it will give you one (first value) encoding the file can be opened with without errors.

Here it the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs


def get_file_bom_encoding(filename):
    with open (filename, 'rb') as openfileobject:
        line = str(openfileobject.readline())
        if line[2:14] == str(codecs.BOM_UTF8).split("'")[1]: return 'utf_8'
        if line[2:10] == str(codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE).split("'")[1]: return 'utf_16'
        if line[2:10] == str(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE).split("'")[1]: return 'utf_16'
        if line[2:18] == str(codecs.BOM_UTF32_BE).split("'")[1]: return 'utf_32'
        if line[2:18] == str(codecs.BOM_UTF32_LE).split("'")[1]: return 'utf_32'
    return ''

def get_all_file_encodings(filename):
    encoding_list = []
    encodings = ('utf_8', 'utf_16', 'utf_16_le', 'utf_16_be', 
                 'utf_32', 'utf_32_be', 'utf_32_le',
                 'cp850' , 'cp437', 'cp852', 'cp1252', 'cp1250' , 'ascii',
                 'utf_8_sig', 'big5', 'big5hkscs', 'cp037', 'cp424', 'cp500',
                 'cp720', 'cp737', 'cp775', 'cp855', 'cp856', 'cp857',
                 'cp858', 'cp860', 'cp861', 'cp862', 'cp863', 'cp864',
                 'cp865', 'cp866', 'cp869', 'cp874', 'cp875', 'cp932',
                 'cp949', 'cp950', 'cp1006', 'cp1026', 'cp1140', 'cp1251',
                 'cp1253', 'cp1254', 'cp1255', 'cp1256', 'cp1257', 
                 'cp1258', 'euc_jp', 'euc_jis_2004', 'euc_jisx0213',
                 'euc_kr', 'gb2312', 'gbk', 'gb18030', 'hz', 'iso2022_jp',
                 'iso2022_jp_1', 'iso2022_jp_2', 'iso2022_jp_2004',
                 'iso2022_jp_3', 'iso2022_jp_ext', 'iso2022_kr', 'latin_1',
                 'iso8859_2', 'iso8859_3', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_5',
                 'iso8859_6', 'iso8859_7', 'iso8859_8', 'iso8859_9',
                 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_13', 'iso8859_14', 'iso8859_15',
                 'iso8859_16', 'johab', 'koi8_r', 'koi8_u', 'mac_cyrillic',
                 'mac_greek', 'mac_iceland', 'mac_latin2', 'mac_roman',
                 'mac_turkish', 'ptcp154', 'shift_jis', 'shift_jis_2004',
                 'shift_jisx0213'
                 )  
    for e in encodings:
        try:
            fh = codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding=e)
            fh.readlines()
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            fh.close()
        except UnicodeError:
            fh.close()
        else:
            encoding_list.append([e])
            fh.close()
            continue     
    return encoding_list

def get_file_encoding(filename):
        file_encoding = get_file_bom_encoding(filename)
        if file_encoding != '':
            return file_encoding
        encoding_list = get_all_file_encodings(filename)
        file_encoding = str(encoding_list[0][0])
        if file_encoding[-3:] == '_be' or file_encoding[-3:] == '_le':
            file_encoding = file_encoding[:-3]
        return file_encoding        

def main():
    print('This Python script is only for import functionality, it does not run interactively')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am sure that there are modules/packages which can do this more accurately, but this is done with standard packages (which was another requirement I had)

It does mean that you are reading the files multiple times, which is not a very fast way of doing things. You may be able to use this to suite your own particular problem, or even improve on this, especially the "reading multiple times" is something which you could look at, and immediately open the file once one encoding is found.